503 Service Unavailable with OpenTelemetry Prometheus HTTPListener
I've instrumented my .Net 6.0 application with System.Disgnostics.DisgnosticSource (8.0.1) and can see my metrics reported by dotnet-counters. I then added an OpenTelemetry OLTP Exporter (1.9.0-alpha.1) which successfully pushes metrics to Prometheus. However, after adding the OpenTelemetry Prometheus HTTPListener Exporter (1.9.0-alpha.2) to my application, Prometheus is connecting to my endpoint, but receives a 503 Service is unavailable error each time. I'm running out of ideas for where to look next to debug this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?
This is my code:
Imports System.Diagnostics.Metrics
Imports OpenTelemetry
Imports OpenTelemetry.Metrics
Imports OpenTelemetry.Exporter

Public Class Form1

  Public Const c_Instrumentation As Boolean = True
  Public Const c_Instrumentation_Push As Boolean = False

  Public Enum ThreadStates
    Stopped
    Starting
    Started
    Stopping
  End Enum

  Public m_State as ThreadStates

  Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If c_Instrumentation Then CreateInstrumentation()

  End Sub

  Public Sub CreateInstrumentation()

    m_Metrics = New Meter("MyApp")

    m_Metrics.CreateObservableGauge(Of Integer)("State", AddressOf Report_State, String.Empty, "Application run-state")

    Dim Builder As MeterProviderBuilder = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    Builder.AddMeter(m_Metrics.Name)

    If c_Instrumentation_Push Then

        Builder.AddOtlpExporter(Sub(exporterOptions, metricReaderOptions)
                                    exporterOptions.Endpoint = New Uri("http://192.168.1.1:9090/api/v1/otlp/v1/metrics")
                                    exporterOptions.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf
                                    metricReaderOptions.TemporalityPreference = MetricReaderTemporalityPreference.Cumulative
                                    metricReaderOptions.PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions.ExportIntervalMilliseconds = 1000
                                End Sub)

    Else

        ' Ensure you run the following on the host machine:
        '     netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:8888/metrics user=\Everyone

        Builder.AddPrometheusHttpListener(Sub(exporterOptions)
                                              Dim Prefixes As String() = {"http://+:8888/metrics/"}
                                              exporterOptions.UriPrefixes = Prefixes
                                          End Sub)

    End If

    m_MetricsExporter = Builder.Build()

  End Sub

  Public Function Report_State() As Integer

    Return m_State

  End Function

End Class

I have run the netsh http add urlacl command shown in the code above, and the netsh http show urlacl command returns:
URL Reservations:
-----------------

    Reserved URL            : http://+:8888/metrics/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Running the application with c_Instrumentation_Push = False, Prometheus and curl both receive:
$ curl http://localhost:8888/metrics
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

UPDATE:
I noticed that the netsh http servicestate command was returning a reference to a server session with the registered URL:
HTTP://+:8888/METRICS/METRICS/
Whereas I was expecting to see:
HTTP://+:8888/METRICS/
So I experimented by replacing the prefix in my code with:
Dim Prefixes As String() = {"http://+:8888/"}
And re-registered the URI with HTTP.sys:
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:8888/metrics
netsh http add urlacl url="http://+:8888/" user=Everyone

(Note the slight change to the URL in the second command - not sure if the quotes are significant, nor the move from * to +)
Prometheus is now connecting successfully.
To be fair, I seem to have added the problematic "/metrics" to my prefix despite the guidance showing examples without it. So my own fault.

This issue seems related to how the URL is configured for the OpenTelemetry Prometheus HTTPListener, especially with HTTP.sys. I faced a similar 503 error when Prometheus was unable to scrape a /health_metrics endpoint in a .NET Core app. In my case, the problem was due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policies blocking the request, but the resolution was tied to endpoint configuration and HTTP settings. You can refer to my detailed solution here: StackOverflow Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79194824/308578
